# How to move an object along with touch drag/swipe by finger-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I want to implement a touch control for an object.When I swipe continuously, without taking the finger from screen,object also has to move along that way.

1.if single touch,object should not move.

2.if swipes/drags a little,object has to move little in that direction.if swipes/drags more,object should move more.

I found this game in play store with the same type of control I want to implement.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bentostudio.ballsvsblocks&hl=en

I implemented basic swipe control like this.

fling() in my inputprocessor class is like this ;

```
 public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    if (Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY)) {
        if (velocityX > 8) {
            this.isSwipeRight = true;
        } else  if (velocityX < 0) {
            this.isSwipeLeft = true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

and handling swipe in update() like this:

```
    private void handleSwipe() {
    if (MyInputProcessor.isSwipeLeft) {
        obj.moveLeft();
        System.out.println("u swiped left");
        MyInputProcessor.isSwipeLeft = false;
    } else if (MyInputProcessor.isSwipeRight) {
        obj.moveRight();
        System.out.println("u swiped right");
        MyInputProcessor.isSwipeRight = false;
    }
}
```

and method to move the object:

```
private float xSpeed=0;
private float leftAccel = 5f;
private float rightAccel = 5f;

public void moveLeft() {
    xSpeed-= leftAccel;
    setPosition(getX()+xSpeed, getY());
}

public void moveRight() {
    xSpeed= rightAccel;
    setPosition(getX()+xSpeed, getY());

}
```

But I am not able to make it work.Only basic swipe is working.Wondering how can I make that smoothness while finger swipe on screen.

Is touchDragged() is the better option for this?

Comment: You don't need swipe for this. You can just use Gdx.input.getX();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing is for quick short moves. For longer continuous finger move you should us pan method:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.GestureAdapter.html#pan-float-float-float-float-

Comment: But with pan,how can I get direction?Please share if any idea.

Comment: Every time your pan method is called you also get coordinates. Store them into some variable for upcoming cals, compare stored ones with new ones. Larger X then it was before means panning to right. Smaller X meants to left. Basic math.